# Entity Framework - add or subtract set amount from DB field

Tags: entity-framework

I am working on my first project using an ORM (currently using Entiry Framework, although that's not set in stone) and am unsure what is the best practice when I need to add or subtract a given amount from a database field, when I am not interested in the new value and I know the field in question is frequently updated, so concurrency conflicts are a concern.

For example, in a retail system where I am recording a sale, as well as creating records for the sale and each of the line items, I need to update the quantity on hand of the items sold. It seems unnecessary to query the database for the existing quantity on hand, just so that I can populate the entity model before saving the updated quantity - and in the time taken for that round-trip, there is a chance that the same item will have been sold through another checkout or the website, so I either have a conflict or (if using a transaction) the other sale is blocked until I complete my update.

In SQL I would simply write
    UPDATE Item SET Quantity=Quantity-1 WHERE ...

It seems the best option in this case is to fall back to ADO.NET + stored procedure for this one update, but is there a better way within Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. ORMs are specialized in tracking changes to each individual entity, and applying those changes to the DB individually. Some ORMs support sending thechanges in btaches, but, even so, to modify all the records in a table implies reading them all, modifyng each one, and sending the changes back to the DB  as individual `UPDATE`s.

And that's a big no-no! as you have corectly thought. It implies loading all the rows into memory, modifying all of them, track their changes, and send them back to the DB as indivudal updates, which is way more expensive that running a single `UPDATE` on the DB.

As to the final question, to run a SQL command you don't need to use traditional ADO.NET. You can run SQL queries directly from an EF `DbContext` using [ExecuteSqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679456%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) like this:

```
MyDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand('Your SQL here!!');
```

I recommend you to look at [the MSDN docs for Database class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database%28v=vs.113%29.aspx), to learn all the things that can be done, for example managing transactions, executing commands that return no data (as the previous example) or executing queries that return data, and even mapping them to entities (classes) in your model: [SqlQuery()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545%28v=vs.113%29.aspx).

So you can run SQL commands and queries without using a different technology.